# Cloud brushes for Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a brush in Photoshop that can create "cartoon" clouds like the image below?

[image]

Comment: Deviant art has a lot of brushes: http://browse.deviantart.com/?qh=&section=&q=cloud%20brushes

Comment: Cartoon clouds are also easily hand-made in photoshop by simply using circles.

Comment: @Lollero Thanks for your feedback. I've searched deviant, but I could not find something like this.

Comment: @Johannes I know its easy but its those 5 minutes I'd like to spend somewhere else, like coding.

Comment: However, just like programming, you can reuse what you've once made. It's a one-time deal kinda thing :]

Comment: You can create own brush shapes using photoshop. Google on how to create photoshop brush. It's simple and easy.

Comment: ..and making like 7 circles and duplicating those twice and doing 1 invert and one gradient addition is not a big deal, like 30second job. Fasters than if you look for a brush to do it.

Comment: This looks more like a vector graphic, which is typically better handled in Illustrator if you have it. Illustrator graphics can then be imported into photoshop - and vice versa.

Comment: this seems more on-topic for graphicdesign.stackexchange.com than here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link with my Cartoon Clouds Brush set for Photoshop:
http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/resources/cloud-brushes-for-photoshop.aspx

but to obtain a result with two colors(blue and black outline) you might want to try to make your own brushes using these cloud vector shapes: 
http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/resources/cloud-shape-vectors-for-photoshop.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to download a set of cartoon brushes which I have an use - [Cartoon Brushes](http://freephotoshop.org/2008/12/free-brushes-28/) - Free Photoshop.org has quite a few brushes also as mentioned above Deviant Art has many. In the future google what you need - `Carton Cloud Photoshop Brushes` and you will find stuff.

Regardless of what brushes you download you are going to have to do a little bit of work to obtain the look you want.

Answer (score 1):

Defiantly try this website: http://www.deviantart.com/browse/all/resources/applications/psbrushes/?q=comic

They offer not only the cartoon brushes but a bunch of other stuff as well.